# TWIG FORM input 'choice_widget', How to apply `transchoices` on choices `ChoiceView` type label?

Tags: php, twig, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using SYMFONY 3 and TWIG.

I have in my translation file "[MySymfProject]\MyBundle\Resources\translations\messages.fr.yml" this:

```
MyBundle:
   label:
        all_saints: "Toussaint | La Toussaint"
        bastille_day: "14 juillet | Le 14 juillet"
```

I want my `<input type="choice">` menu to display "Toussaint" (**That does not work, I get "Toussaint | La Toussaint" displayed in the menu**). And then it should display "La Toussaint" in another field (that works, with JS translation bundle, I use the TransChoice function and select the index corresponding to "La Toussaint" for translation word tag "all_saints").

I've tried to alter the TWIG template based on `{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}`.

And do something like:

```
{% block form_row  %}

         {% if  (form.vars.block_prefixes.1 == "choice") %}
            {% for choice in form.vars.choices %}
                {% set choice.label = choice.label|transchoice(1) %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% block choice_widget %}
                {{ parent() }}  
            {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But that does not work, it seems that I cannot alter values of an object that is being processed thru a loop in TWIG.

Any idea?

Comment: You could inject the translator in your form and call the transchoice method from it

Comment: yes I am thinking about that (if you mean the AbstractType extended Class).

Comment: Put my thoughts in answer

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType as BaseAbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

private $translator;

public function __construct(Translator $translator)
{
    $this->translator = $translator;
}


class AbstractType extends BaseAbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        parent::configureOptions();
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return BaseAbstractType::class;
    }
}


services:
    app.form.type.abstract:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\AbstractType
        arguments:
            - '@translator'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Then you extend all your custom forms from this new AbstractType

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I've upvoted because it is a good workaround but it is not the solution that I expect (things are going a bit spaghetti:)) so won't validate as the good answer. That stuff should be fixable thru TWIG I believe.

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes ?

Comment: which quotes do you refer to?

Comment: all_saints: "Toussaint | La Toussaint"

Comment: It does not change anything, get me back to square #1 (same as I've described in the intial issue) :)

Comment: And what about all_saints: {1} Toussaint | {2} La Toussaint. If this does not work either maybe you should consider to make two different messages

Comment: The point is not to make two different messages. I think the solution would be to override"label" in "choice_widget" of https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig, but what is implemented by default seems rather complex